SOQL Query - List of opportunities with at least one sibling
Does anyone know if it's possible to return a list of opportunities that have at least one sibling opportunity?  I'm having a hard time finding anything on this, aside from this post on the trailblazer community: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54V000077C5SeSAK
I was also suggested the question here.  But this question is in regards to querying the parent records in a relationship, where I'm looking to return the child records.
I know I can query Accounts that have at least two opportunities, and then use that list to get the opportunities.  But I was curious if anyone knows how to do this in a single query or if it's even possible.

This question is similar to: How to query records having at least one valid child record?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@NickC I'm not sure how that question is similar to mine.  I'm trying to return a list of child records, whereas that question is regards to returning a list of parent records.

Sorry, I misread 'sibling' as 'child'

No worries, I've updated my question stating how your suggestion is different.

Step 1; rollup number of opportunities to parent Account via your favorite framework. Step 2: profit.

Thanks @identigral.  Any idea how to do this with a query?

select count(id), accountId from opportunity group by accountId having count(id) > 1 finds all accounts with 2+ Oppos; from there you can query again for Opportunities; otherwise you need identigral's solution

Thanks @cropredy - I was hoping I wouldn't need two queries, but figured that'd be case.
